# Debugging Jest tests in VSCode does nothing

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm trying to get debugging working with my NodeJS Jest tests in VSCode. I can run the tests **without** debugging fine, but trying extensions or debug options does nothing - meaning the tests don't run at all. I have a couple of breakpoints set - one is in a test, and the other is in the service file I'm trying to test.

Here's what I've tried:

My current `launch.json` file (I've tried other configurations that I've since removed):

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Jest Current File",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "args": [
          "--runTestsByPath",
          "${relativeFile}",
          "--config",
          "jest.config.js"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
        "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Jest", // This is the configuration name you will see in debug sidebar
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 5858,
        "address": "localhost",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "--inspect-brk", // node v8 use debug-brk if older version of node
          "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
          "--watch",
          "--bail",
          "--runInBand"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
```

When clicking the green Play button (while the test file is open in the editor) for either of these under the "Run and Debug" tab, it looks like the debug options pop up for about a second, then they disappear and nothing happens.

In my `package.json` file, my test script looks as follows:
`"test": "jest --watch --verbose"`

and I've tried running `npm test` in a Javascript Debug Terminal. This runs the tests, but does not stop at the breakpoints I've set.

I've also tried a few extensions, such as "Jest", "Jest Runner" and "Jest Run It" - all having the same result of nothing happening when trying to run debug.

I'm running on a Windows 10 machine with my terminals in WSL Ubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow the following setup:

`launch.json`

```
        {
            "name": "Jest file",
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "--runInBand",
                "--watch",
                "--coverage=false",
                "--no-cache"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "windows": {
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
            }
        },
```

Verify these libraries on `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1"
  }
```

The proposed configuration should let you debug your jest files

Comment: The only thing I needed to do additionaly is specify the jest.config.js. Works well. Thank you.